# Pointer to object and its destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, delete-operator

```
class finder
{
    public:
        finder();
        ~finder();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    finder* pfind = new finder(L"test");
    finder find(L"test2");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

What I know that find's destructor will be called after program exit, but pfind's destructor won't be called. My question is why? And Should I add

```
delete _pfind;
```

before return 0?

Comment: You shouldn't add `delete`, you should remove `new`.

Comment: Your code is full of errors; if you're going to post snippets you should try to make them as correct as possible.

Comment: @avakar there's nothing wrong with learning about `new` and `delete`. Sure you can find ways to avoid them if you don't like them, but there's nothing wrong with actually using them and getting comfortable with them and learning from your mistakes and deciding whether you like them or not.

Answer (score 3):

The "why" is because you're responsible for managing the lifetime of objects you create with `new`.

The language says that objects with automatic storage duration (like `find` in your example) live as long as the block in which they are created. These get automatically deleted (you must not do it yourself) at the appropriate time (i.e. generally when you leave that block.)

Dynamic storage duration objects (like what `pfind` points to) last until you delete them. Nothing will delete them for you.

So yes, you need to delete it yourself in this case, with `delete pfind;`.

(Or use the appropriate type of smart pointer for your use case.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should explicitly clean up the memory you allocate by calling `delete` on your unmanaged pointers. Typically any block of code which allocates memory via `new` must be balanced by a block of code which deallocates that memory via `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Mat is right, however I noticed you are using CLR/.Net C++ (or whatever they call it these days). I believe this comes with a `gcnew` keyword which will do the same thing as the `new` keyword but delete the object at the end of its scope. This is also known as garbage collection. On a personal note having both `new` and `gcnew` is a great tool because they both fit nicely into diffrent situations. Please keep in mind you code will not be cross-platform if you use `gcnew`.